# How can I display program output to a text box in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.9, pyttsx3

I want to show all the print statements of `takeCommand()` function to
on my UI's text label.
eg. When we run the program it shows output in terminal usually like

Listening...
Recognizing...
User said:

I want the above line to be displayed on my UI's label. (name of the label in this program: labelOutput)
details about the question

```py
import pyttsx3 #Text-to-Speech
import speech_recognition as sr #For speech recognition
import datetime #For current date and time
import wikipedia #pip install wikipedia
import webbrowser #For opening browser commands
import os
import time         #For interacting with operating system
import smtplib    #send mails using gmail.
import pyjokes
import socket
import requests
import PyPDF2
import pyautogui
import pywhatkit
import wolframalpha
import instaloader
import cv2
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer,QTime,QDate,Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
engine. setProperty("rate", 180)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def Intro_Jarvis():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak("Good Morning Sir!")

    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak("Good Afternoon Sir!")   

    else:
        speak("Good Evening Sir!")  

    speak("Allow me to introduce myself. I am Jarvis, A virtual artificial intelligence and I am here to assist you with the variety of tasks as best as I can. System is now fully operational.")    

class MainThread(QThread):
       
       def __init__(self):
           super(MainThread,self).__init__()
       
       def run(self):
           self.TaskExecution()
       
       def takeCommand(self):
            r = sr.Recognizer()
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                print("Listening...") 
                r.pause_threshold = 1
                audio = r.listen(source)

            try:
                print("Recognizing...")    
                query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
                print(f"User said: {query}\n")

            except Exception as e:
                # print(e)    
                print("Say that again please...")  
                return "None"
            return query

       def TaskExecution(self):
         Intro_Jarvis()
         while True:
        # if 1:
            self.query = self.takeCommand().lower()
            elif "hello" in self.query or "hey" in self.query or "hi" in self.query:
                speak("hello sir, may I help you with something.")

            elif "how are you" in self.query :
                speak("I am fine sir, what about you?")

            elif "thank you" in self.query or "thanks" in self.query:
                speak("It's my pleasure sir.")

            elif "read pdf" in self.query or "read a pdf file" in self.query:
                book = open("File.pdf","rb")
                pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book)
                pages=pdfReader.numPages
                speak(f"Total pages in this book are {pages}")
                speak("Please tell me the page number")
                page_number=int(input("Page Number : "))
                page=pdfReader.getPage(page_number)
                text=page.extractText()
                speak(text)
            
            elif "open youtube" in self.query or "search on youtube" in self.query:
                speak("What you want search on YouTube")
                response=self.takeCommand()
                speak(f"Okay, Searching {response} on YouTube")
                webBrowerOpen(f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={response}") 
                
            elif  "goodbye"in self.query:
                speak("Thanks for giving me the chance to help you, have a good day sir")
                exit()

startExecution=MainThread()

class Main(QMainWindow):
       
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.ui=Ui_Dialog()
           self.ui.setupUi(self) 
           self.ui.pushButtonStart.clicked.connect(self.startTask)
           self.ui.movie=QtGui.QMovie("background.jpg")
           self.ui.labelMain.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
           self.ui.movie.start()
           self.ui.pushButtonExit.clicked.connect(self.close)
           
       def startTask(self):
           self.ui.movie=QtGui.QMovie("background.jpg")
           self.ui.labelMain.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
           self.ui.movie.start()
           self.ui.movie=QtGui.QMovie("StartJarvis.gif")
           self.ui.labelJarvisStart.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
           self.ui.movie.start()
           self.ui.movie=QtGui.QMovie("Anim1.gif")
           self.ui.labelAnim1.setMovie(self.ui.movie)
           self.ui.movie.start()
           self.ui.labelOutput.setText()  # I wanted to get The text here from takeCommand 
                                          # Function (eg. "Listening..."  or "Recognizing..."  
           startExecution.start()


app=QApplication(sys.argv)
jarvis=Main()
jarvis.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: i tried to re produce your problem but you provided a peace of code not the complete one so why don't you try setting value like self.label_14.setText("hello user") if you are using a label

Comment: it will also work with textbox

Comment: but the label has to be continuously updated as the program in the terminal updates like: "Listening....   " and then " Recognizing" and then "user said: "

Comment: Is there any way to get the variables of def takeCommand(self)  function in def startTask(self):  function?

Comment: its simple you just need to use self.someVariable = 'hello' and  in any other function juse use self again e.g. print(self.someVariable) #prints hello

Comment: ok, I will try it.